# IndexError while passing value to knn algorithm in the process of implementing aco-pants in python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, prediction, knn

```
import time
import math
import argparse
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
from pants import World, Edge
from pants import Solver
import csv
import random
import math
import operator

a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0

def loadDataset(filename,trainingSet=[],testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        z = len(dataset)-1
        for x in range(len(dataset)-2):
            for y in range(8,9):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])         
        for y in range(8,9):
                dataset[z][y] = float(dataset[z][y])
                testSet.append(dataset[z])


def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2):
    distance = 0
    X= (float(instance1[9]) - float(instance2[9])) +(float(instance1[8]) - float(instance2[8]))
    distance += pow(X, 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)

def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x])
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
        neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors

def main():
    trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    loadDataset('D:\ex.csv', trainingSet, testSet)
    print ('Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet)))
    print ('Test set: ' + repr(len(testSet)))
    k = 4
    neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[0], k)
    l=m=n=0
    print(' Nearest Neighbour is '+a+ '  whose latitude difference is: '+b+ ' and longitude differnce is '+c )
    a=neighbors[0][8]
    b=neighbors[0][9]
    c=neighbors[1][8]
    d=neighbors[1][9]
    e=neighbors[2][8]
    f=neighbors[2][9]
    g=neighbors[3][8]
    h=neighbors[3][9]
# Real-world latitude longitude coordinates.
TEST_COORDS_33 = [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g,h)]
# 45-45-90 triangle with unit length legs.
TEST_COORDS_3 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
# Unit square with diagonals.
TEST_COORDS_4 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]
# Same as above except with additional node in center of left edge.
TEST_COORDS_5 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0.5)]

def dist(a, b):
    """Return the distance between two points represeted as a 2-tuple."""
    return math.sqrt((a[1] - b[1]) ** 2 + (a[0] - b[0]) ** 2)

def run_demo(nodes, *args, **kwargs):
    world = World(nodes, dist)
    solver = Solver(**kwargs)
    columns = "{!s:<25}\t{:<25}"
    divider = "-" * (25 + 25)
    header = columns.format("Time Elapsed", "Distance")
    columns = columns.replace('<', '>', 1)
    fastest = None
    start_time = time.time()
    for i, ant in enumerate(solver.solutions(world)):
            fastest = ant
            fastest_time = timedelta(seconds=(time.time() - start_time))
            print(columns.format(fastest_time, ant.distance))
    total_time = timedelta(seconds=(time.time() - start_time))
    print("Best solution:")
    for i, n in zip(fastest.visited, fastest.tour):
        print("  {:>8} = {}".format(i, n))
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        epilog = "\n".join([
            'For best results:',
            '  * 0.5 <= A <= 1',
            '  * 1.0 <= B <= 5',
            '  * A < B',
            '  * L >= 2000',
            '  * N > 1',
            '',
            ('For more information, please visit '
             'https://github.com/rhgrant10/Pants.')
            ])
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Script that demos the ACO-Pants package.',
            epilog=epilog,
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-V', '--version',
            action='version',
            version='%(prog)s 0.5.1',
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-a','--alpha',
            type=float, default=1,
            help='relative importance placed on pheromones; default=%(default)s',
            metavar='A'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-b', '--beta',
            type=float, default=3,
            help='relative importance placed on distances; default=%(default)s',
            metavar='B'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-l', '--limit',
            type=int, default=100,
            help='number of iterations to perform; default=%(default)s',
            metavar='L')
        parser.add_argument(
            '-p', '--rho',
            type=float, default=0.8,
            help=('ratio of evaporated pheromone (0 <= P <= 1);''default=%(default)s'),
            metavar='P'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-e', '--elite',
            type=float, default=0.5,
            help='ratio of elite ant\'s pheromone; default=%(default)s',
            metavar='E'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-q', '--Q',
            type=float, default=1,
            help=('total pheromone capacity of each ant (Q > 0);''default=%(default)s'),
            metavar='Q'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-t', '--t0',
            type=float, default=0.01,
            help=('initial amount of pheromone on every edge (T > 0); ''default=%(default)s'),
            metavar='T'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-c', '--count',dest='ant_count',
            type=int, default=10,
            help=('number of ants used in each iteration (N > 0); ''default=%(default)s'),
            metavar='N'
            )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-d', '--dataset',
            type=int, default=33,choices=[3, 4, 5, 33],
            help='specify a particular set of demo data; default=%(default)s',
            metavar='D'
            )
        args = parser.parse_args()
        nodes = {
            3: TEST_COORDS_3 ,
            4: TEST_COORDS_4 ,
            5: TEST_COORDS_5 ,
            33: TEST_COORDS_33
        }[args.dataset]                
        run_demo(nodes, **args.__dict__)

main()
```

[Screenshot Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvldL.jpg)
I am trying to implement knn on a dataset and use its result as an input for implementing ant colony algorithm but am stucked sincs last few hours as they are working completely fine when executed separately but while implementing both together code is giving few errors. Actually i have tried each and every way but i am not able to deduce any legit problem in my code .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/sam.py", line 178, in <module>  
    main()  
File "C:/sam.py", line 49, in main  
    loadDataset('D:\ex.csv', trainingSet, testSet)  
  File "C:/sam.py", line 22, in loadDataset  
    dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please paste your error (don't use a screenshot)

Comment: sure i have updated same with output in text format